# Error parsing font string in matplotlib stylesheet

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I want to use a custom font in my matplotlib plots. I would like to use path of the .ttf file in the stylesheet, for example:

```
mathtext.it: "/path/to/fontname-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf"
```

But when using this stylesheet the python script gives the following warning:

> Bad value in file '~/path/to/stylesheet.mplstyle', line 30
> ('mathtext.it:  "/path/to/fontname-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf"'):
> Key mathtext.it: Could not parse font string:
> '"/path/to/fontname-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf"' Expected end of
> text, found '-'  (at char 36), (line:1, col:37)

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional by matplotlib. The string is not enough to import the font.

> Note that passing paths as `str`s is intentionally not supported, but you can simply wrap strs in `pathlib.Paths` as needed.

More information here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/font_file.html

So you have to do something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
yourFont = Path("/path/to/fontname-Italic-VariableFont_wght.ttf")
```

Then you can use the `yourFont` string as an input to a `font` argument.